# work with intellij IDEA instead of netbeans on github repository

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, netbeans

We are five students working in the same project.This project was created with Netbeans, and we have a repository on gitHub.
I want to use Intellij and the four team members are using NetbeansIDE  so  can i work on this repository using Intellij IDE, without break the repo...if yes how can i do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java source code is stored as plain text. You could have a person on your team using Notepad and it wouldn't make a difference. I will include a few caveats to this statement, however:

1. Don't add any IntelliJ IDEA or Netbeans files to the project. You can add the entire `.idea` folder to your `.gitignore`. I'm not sure if Netbeans has a similar folder.
2. Make sure your team agrees on tabs vs. spaces, indentation level, etc. Both IDEs include tools to format your code, so you want to keep it consistent.

Comment: You could use editorconfig for formatting decisions. I know IntelliJ supports it via the editorconfig plugin, but not sure about NetBeans. EditorConfig allows you to be consistent with things like tabs vs spaces and be agnostic of which IDE developers decide to use.

Comment: There is a site you can use to make sure you have included all IDE specific files to your `.gitignore` -> https://www.gitignore.io/

Answer (score 1):

Making the project a maven/gradle project would be a great solution. This way managing the build and dependencies of the project will be independent from the IDE, development parties are using.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! If you have a .gitignore just ignore the files that the respective ides e.g .idea for IntelliJ.